# Using a C++ Class to Define Multiple Data Structures

Tags: c++, class, struct

I'm having trouble with a simple concept that comes from my previous experience with C and how it transfers to C++.  In C you would see a header file with several structure type definitions that could be used across the code base.  I then saw a C++ class usage similar to below:

```
//varTypes.h
class varTypes
{
  public:
    struct TypeOne {int a; int b;};
    struct TypeTwo {int c; int d;};
}

//varTypes.cpp
include "varTypes.h"

varTypes::TypeOne x {1, 1};
varTypes::TypeTwo y {1, 2};
varTypes::TypeTwo z {2, 4};
```

In this case the class appears to be only used to contain definitions that can be used individually as needed.  Is this true? Or do the class and two definitions always exist together as members for each instance they are used, i.e. do x, y, and z end up as whole varType classes instances or as their individual structures?

Simple C code for reference

```
//varTypes.h
struct TypeOne {int a; int b;};
struct TypeTwo {int c; int d;};

//varTypes.c
include "varTypes.h"

varTypes::TypeOne x {1, 1};
varTypes::TypeTwo y {1, 2};
varTypes::TypeTwo z {2, 4};
```

Comment: Can you show what you used to use in C?  All this class does is act like a namespace (It scopes the names of the nested classes to the outer class).

Comment: If you look at it carefully the class has no member variables.  A varTypes object holds nothing.  Like  @NathanOliver says it's just a namespace.

Comment: @NathanOliver, Dave S, Thanks, that's the simple answer.  A class with no member variables functions as a namespace.  For some reason that was escaping me.  I'll add the C code for reference.

Answer (score 0):

A class with no member variables functions as a namespace.